# How to create a Stacked Bar Chart with my data set created?

Tags: spagobi

I have just now deployed a SpagoBI server and after setting up my data source: MS SQL Server.

I am able to successfully create a data set. Now using my data set I want to create a stacked bar chart. So I select Charts->Stacked but to my surprise that perhaps a default stackbar of "Sales, costs and revenues over the year Monthly detail - Year: 2012" always comes up. I was not able to see charts for my data set.

However I still see my data set there. I tried many ways to use the output of my data set for stack bar but un-fortunately always the default chart comes up?

How can I create a Stacked Bar Chart with my data set created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you creating dashboard in SpagoBI Studio 5.1 then

1.Click on project and Create under SpagoBI.

2.Click on window  - others perspective - choose - report design.

3.In report design  - create Report - under Business Analysis folder finish.

4.Right Click on data source  create - new data source and choose your db as per your  requirement.

5.then , data set.

6.then create your dashboard as you want to create.

7.When you deploy your report in SpagoBI server again click on windows - other perspective  - choose SpagoBI

8.Expand your project and you see a Server name folder then right click on server provide SpagoBI  url and password

9.Right click on report provide name all the credential. and deploy.

Try this Prakash.

Comment: Thanks - I was off at work - this way it works but what about the XML / template method? Is there any documentation of these tools - I need them badly?

Answer (score 1):

1.First, write xml related to your query in database.
2.then , log in to SpagoBI server then create datasource-> dataset-> choose document.
3.Fill all the informaion, and there is an Template option browse the xml file in it.
4.And create Analytical driver management and lov management related to your query columns thatyou wants to choose.
5.And run the report document.

Comment: Please let me know how to write XML related to the query? Which tool should I make use for same - what are its steps to create?

Comment: Sorry I am using Spago 5.1 Studio and BI server - until now I have created a file dashboard.rptdesign - please provide step by step how to create the XML you have mentioned - even if you have developed the same on some other version please share I can switch to that version also